# How would I fit both a dishwasher and a washing machine with this plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

What parts do I need to hook both units to this sink?

[image: Under sink]

[image: Tap]

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking, you need to provide much more details and what you hope to accomplish. But be aware washing machines cannot be plumbed to sinks, they require their own separate plumbing. On the other hand dishwashers are plumbed to sinks.

Comment: What extensions do I need to buy so that I am able to plumb in a sink and a dishwasher to these current connections.

Comment: You should be able to download the fitting instructions for each appliance to see what will be needed.

Comment: If do you not know how to install a dishwasher then having the parts is not going to be useful to you until you have the knowledge to use them.

Once you do some research and educate yourself as to how the install a dishwasher then you will have the knowledge to know what plumbing parts to buy.    https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-install-dishwasher

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can physically fit a dishwasher and a washing machine between your cabinets, you would need to replace two parts.

- Replace the trap under the sink with one that has connections for two appliances.
- Replace the blue shut off valve with one that also has two connections.

Here are a couple of parts that should work.

[image: Floplast dual sink and wash trap from Screwfix]
[image: Compression appliance tee from Screwfix]

This is all feasible by a DIY'er but might require some extra fittings or cuts to the shelf to make the new trap fit. You might also be able to find a similar valve but push-fit and easier to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a washing machine to this connection. You can add a dishwasher with a [Plastic Dishwasher Branch Tailpiece](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Plastic-Dishwasher-Branch-Tailpiece-Direct-Connect-or-Slip-Joint/46650212?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1609&adid=22222222227034022431&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=55462579298&wl4=pla-86387595218&wl5=9029988&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=113487702&wl11=online&wl12=46650212&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhb_386aK3wIVgvhkCh1VnQ5HEAQYAiABEgKZNvD_BwE)

You may have to cut this to size, though, as it looks like you have limited room between your sink bottom and your in-wall plumbing.

Comment: The OP appears to be from the UK where it's common to have a washing machine in the kitchen plumbed into exactly this type of connection (with the addition of a small tail piece where the blanking cap is in the photo). I'm pretty sure they could fit either a dishwasher or a washing machine with hardly any work, but not both.